# Moving to other html through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mongodb

i'm trying to move to my account.html from my login.html, using javascript, where i in login.html there will be a validation from MongoDB. And if it's the same data, it was supposed to go to acoount.html, but it doesn't. This is my javascript:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, AuthService) {
  $scope.data = {};

  $scope.login = function(data) {
           var formdata = {

                   num : $("#num").val(),
                   pw : $("#pw").val()  
            };

            var Jformdata = JSON.stringify(formdata);
            //var url = $location.url();
            console.log(Jformdata);

            $.ajax({
                url : "/ProjectSinarmas/submit",
                context : document.body,
                type : 'POST',
                data : Jformdata,
                contentType : "application/json"
            }).done(function (response){
                //console.log(response);
                if(response == "true"){
                    //$state.go('main.account');
                    var path = $location.path("http://localhost:8089/ProjectSinarmas/templates/account.html");
                    alert("Login Success");
                }else{
                    $scope.showAlert('Nomer Telephone dan PIN Salah');
                }

            });


        };
```

I got this error response from my html:

```
controllers.js:53 Uncaught ReferenceError: $location is not defined
```

Thanks before, and have a nice day.

Comment: can you show what is in the response?

Comment: @snit80 controllers.js:53 Uncaught ReferenceError: $location is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call $location in Controller check below

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state,$location, $ionicPopup, AuthService) {


 //code........

}
```

Comment: it doesn't show any error, but it won't move to my account,html

Comment: but if you need to use "$location.path", you need to define as like above

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding $location to your controller, my guess is you might also need to use the AngularJS [$http method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) (or $post) method instead of $ajax, so that AngularJS knows when your request is completed and handles the scope update.

also change:

```
   var path = $location.path("http://localhost:8089/ProjectSinarmas/templates/account.html");
```

to:

```
    $location.path("http://localhost:8089/ProjectSinarmas/templates/account.html");
```

no need to put in the path var if its not used.

Comment: I tried it like this, and it does't work:$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost:8089/ProjectSinarmas/templates/account.html'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
     $location.path("http://localhost:8089/ProjectSinarmas/templates/account.html");
     alert("Login Success");
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
       $scope.showAlert('Nomer Telephone dan PIN Salah');
      });

Comment: what was the error? the code you posted here you has a semicolon after the url, and you dont need to name the success and error functions, like this: `                $http({method: 'GET', url: 'localhost:8089/ProjectSinarmas/templates/account.html'})
                    .then(function (response) {
                        $location.path("localhost:8089/ProjectSinarmas/template‌​s/account.html");
                        alert("Login Success");
                }, function (response) {
                    $scope.showAlert('Nomer Telephone dan PIN Salah');
                });`

Comment: Your call changed from a POST in the original post, to a GET - that may be an issue.

Comment: This works. you need to include $http in your controller.       ` $http(
            {
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/ProjectSinarmas/submit',
                data: Jformdata,
                headers:    {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                window.location = "http://localhost:8089/ProjectSinarmas/templates/account.html"; `
                alert("Login Success");
            }, function (response) {
                alert('Nomer Telephone dan PIN Salah');
            });